# Fetching from android device localhost using javascript

Tags: javascript, android, localhost, webrtc, fetch

I am developing a web app, that needs to run on android mobile device's browser and, communicate with a mobile app which is installed on that device.

The web app need to communicate through ajax calls to localhost (to the android mobile device) to retrieve data from the mobile app.

So far I tried fetching from: http://localhost, http://127.0.0.1, http://10.0.2.2 and none of them worked.
I succeeded only by getting the device IP using webRTC and fetching from this IP.

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: I don't think that your android mobile browser is able to do anything outside of the browser. You might want to rethink your architecture.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are trying to inspect development on your android device, you need to use Google Chrome, just open localhost on your mobile device and connect via usb to your computer, then use the remote device tool.

Follow the tool link: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging

Comment: I think that OP means that there is an app on the phone which functions as a server/database and she wants to communicate with that app to get data for her web app.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on the same network you can use your internal IP address. If you're using windows you can use `ipconfig` and if you're a MAC user you can use `ifconfig`.

After you found your internal IP address append the port number that your server is running on `internalipaddress:port` and start making requests there.